# How to parent specific objects to newly created collections?

Tags: python, scripting, parent, collections, outliner

I used this python code to set the parent (link) the specific objects to newly created collection. The code is working well, but I can see the same objects instance outside(**Scene Collection**) the newly created collection. I would like to know what should be the reason still objects instances are visible outside(**Scene Collection**) the newly created collection and what should the solution to show the objects under the newly created collection?

```
import bpy

new_collection_name = "NewCollection"
new_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(new_collection_name)
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(new_collection)

object_to_parent = bpy.data.objects.get("rig")
new_collection.objects.link(object_to_parent)
```

This is my output

[image]

But my exception should be like below image, This I did by manually drag and drop the objects to the newly created collection.
How I can get below result via python code?

[image]

If any one can help, that should be appreciable,

Thanks,
Subin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively without operators.

```
import bpy


collection = bpy.data.collections["NewCollection"]
for obj_name in ("rig", "batman_geo"):
    obj = bpy.data.objects[obj_name]
    while obj.users_collection:
        obj.users_collection[0].objects.unlink(obj)
    collection.objects.link(obj)
```

The reason you see a grayed out child in the new collection is because its parent is linked to the collection, but the child is not and you have "Object Children" filter enabled in the outliner settings.

[image]

Note an object can be linked to an arbitrary number of collections, so I first unlink from all linked collections, then link to the new one. In your case *rig* is linked both in the scene collection and in the new collection.

You don't *parent* an object to a collection, because that would imply an exclusive relationship, you *link* an object to a collection.

If you want to recursively link all children of a root object to a specific collection you can use

```
import bpy


collection = bpy.data.collections["NewCollection"]
objects_to_link = [bpy.data.objects["rig"]]
while objects_to_link:
    obj = objects_to_link.pop(0)
    while obj.users_collection:
        obj.users_collection[0].objects.unlink(obj)
    collection.objects.link(obj)
    objects_to_link.extend(obj.children)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gorgious

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead :

```
import bpy


COLLECTION_NAME = "NewCollection"

OBJECT_TO_PARENT = bpy.data.objects.get("rig")


bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

OBJECT_TO_PARENT.select_set(True)


bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection(new_collection_name=COLLECTION_NAME, collection_index=0, is_new=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yaroslav